# Kohana 3.1 Controllers in Sub Folders within the Controller Folder

Tags: kohana-3

I need to create sub folders for my controllers for ease of managing and troubleshooting. I need to have  controller/, controller/admin, controller/user/ kind of setup. I have tried creating the controller in controller/admin/createuser from http://mydomain/admin/createuser but that does not seem to work.

Anyone with tips on this?

Do I need custom routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set up a Route to catch /admin/ and look for an 'directory' called admin rather than a 'controller file' called admin. 
Then your 'createuser' param would ideally be in a 'user' controller, so 'createuser' would be an action in your users controller

---

Note the 'directory' declaration -
**application/bootstrap.php**

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
  ->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action' => 'index',
));
```

---

Then in your controller you need to use underscores for each directory '/' in the Class name 
 - **application/classes/controller/admin/user.php**

```
class Controller_Admin_User extends Controller {

  public function action_createuser()
  {
    ..your code
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I have some sort of SEF urls with this?

Comment: You can use any urls you want with Routes..  just take out the <controller> or what ever, and then tell it what controller you want the specified path to use:  Route::set('loggingIn', 'admin/login')->defaults('controller'=>'user', 'action'=>'login')  they are cascading, so put one like this higher up in page and it will be caught first if the path matches.

Comment: This works. Guaranteed, the 'id' parameter is required. Could you make your route code solution where 'id' would be optional? I take out the (/<id>) or add array('id' => '.*') as a third parameter for Route::set() but it doesn't work.